# vlcj:: Unable to load library 'libvlc' in 64bit OS

Tags: stream, vlc, libvlc, vlcj

I am using 64 bit OS Windows 7 and i have 32 bit VLC versioned 1.1.8.

I have added these libraries
`jna.jar
platform.jar
vlcj-1.1.5.1.jar`

I am not able to stream using jVlc

```
public class HelloVLC {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println( WindowsRuntimeUtil.getVlcInstallDir());
      NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("libvlc", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
      String media = "dshow://";
     String[] options = {" :dshow-vdev=Integrated Webcam :dshow-adev=  :dshow-caching=200", ":sout = #transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,scale=0.25,acodec=vorb,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:display :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :ttl=1 :sout-keep"};
        System.out.println("Streaming '" + media + "' to '" + options + "'");

        MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
        final HeadlessMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newMediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.playMedia(media, options);
}
```

}

I am getting the error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libvlc': The specified module could not be found.`

Kindly help. Is there any way to get this code work in 64 bit OS????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have you tried running it with a 32-bit JVM?

Comment: I was using 64bit eclipse which needed 64bit JVM. I had both 32 bit 1.6 aand 64bit 1.7 JVM. Now i moved to 32 bit JVM and 32 bit eclipse.Now everything is working fine for me.Thanx

Comment: 64bit VLC also would have been the choice ..i think..is n't it??i did n't get a working 64 bit VLC.No problem..32 bits are working for me now

Comment: there's no windows 64 bit VLC [yet]

Comment: Yes there is no 64bit VLC,unless we get an error free 64bit build VLC

Answer (score 6):

if you are using windows 7 then search for a file libvlc.dll and libvlccore.dll files in to your vlc installation and add their path to code that you've written  in
NativeLibrary.addSearchPath() also add...

this worked me in my case windows 7.

```
 NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(
                RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), ""c:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/");
        Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
        LibXUtil.initialise();
```

Answer (score 1):

VLCj comes with automagic discovery methods, os-independent, that adds the relevent path to JNA:s search path:

```
 NativeDiscovery nd = new NativeDiscovery();
 if (!nd.discover()) {
     System.out.println("VLC not found");
     System.exit(-1);
 }   
 String vlcLibName = RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcName();
 String vlcLibCoreName = RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcCoreName();
 Native.loadLibrary(vlcLibName, LibVlc.class);
```

...etc
for a good tutorial on how to load the VLC natives, see 
http://capricasoftware.co.uk/#/projects/vlcj/tutorial/first-steps
(See also the previous steps in that tutorial)!